# Updating Realm Data When Version Changed

Tags: android, version, realm

I have two language arrays in my arrays.xml. All languages and default languages.

I have a Language class which has two fields. Name and isSelected.

I am adding all languages to my Realm database on First run of my app. I am setting isSelected field of language if the language is in default languages array.

My question is when I update the all languages in my arrays.xml and publish an update for my app, how can I get the old realm data for selected languages and then clear the realm db and create a brand new with all languages in my arrays.xml and set the isSelected with the old realm data for selected languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you just want to update existing language data and add non exciting language data, then you can use,

`realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> realm1.copyToRealmOrUpdate(languageList));`

2. If you want to delete all language data before adding the updated one as a fresh copy, then you can first delete all language data and add new list like this,

`realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> realm1.delete(LanguageClass.class));
 realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> realm1.copyToRealmOrUpdate(languageList));`

3. In case you want to delete entire Realm database file first before adding the new data, you can first delete the entire Realm, which will delete LanguageClass data and any other Realm class you may have, like this,

`Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration);
 realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> realm1.copyToRealmOrUpdate(languageList));`

NOTE: The most recommended option in your case would option no.1, which is the most safe and reliable way to update data in Realm.

NOTE2: Instead of copying language data every time, you should only copy/update language data when there is a change in the language data.

Comment: I want to get old data first and then delete the Language class data completely and finally create a brand new database by using old data and my updated language. I should do that only if I update my languages in arrays.xml and then publish an update.

Comment: What is the problem then? use List<LanguageClass> languageList = realm.where(GitHubUserRealm.class).findAll(); to get existing language data if any, and use option-2 given in the answer to delete and create a fresh Language database.

Comment: Where should I do that? It should update only if I change arrays.xml and send update for app.

Comment: In your Application class, where you create your RealmConfiguration and set it as default. Create an update utility file, which should have a method e.g. checkIfLanguageDataUpdateNeeded(), that should compare arrays.xml data and Realm data, if different recreate Realm data, else do nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much, Viraj Tank.